# React BrowserRouter - url not working in build (401)

Tags: reactjs, url, build, react-router, react-router-dom

when I use this switch with the **browser router**, the url runs in dev version just fine, but not in **build**, the **url e.g. .../list of documents shows Error 401**.

I use server React v17, Parcel 2.0, server kestrel on .net.

Here are dependencies and devDependencies in my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/utils": "^4.11.2",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^4.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.13.3",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "material-ui-dropzone": "^3.5.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
  }
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.13.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.13.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.13",
    "@parcel/transformer-image": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
    "eslint": "^7.18.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-material-ui": "^1.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "parcel": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1"
  }
```

And here is my browser router in App.js:

```
<Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Grid>
              <Main />
            </Grid>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/list-of-documents">
            <Grid>
              <ListofDocuments />
            </Grid>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
```

Does anyone have any idea why it is not working in build?

Comment: Where are you deploying your app to, a sub-directory? What is the homepage value in your package.json file? Have you tried specifying a basename for your router to match where your app is running from?

Comment: Where are you deploying your app to, a sub-directory?
- yes to a subderictory wwwroot in webapi

What is the homepage value in your package.json file?
- I have tried "homepage" according to our build url: "http://localhost:5000/index.html", but does Parcel even consider it? I thought this is the config for the WebPack

Have you tried specifying a basename for your router to match where your app is running from?
Yes, i even tried to slice the rest of the route given by window.location.href, "/", etc. 

nothing worked so far

Answer (score 0):

you can better use rrd-v-6.

then your code looks like this...

```
<BrowserRouter>
   <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={< Home />} />
      <Route path="/..." element={< yourComponent/>} />
   </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Regards